# Converting a TRON address to Base58 doesn't work

Tags: blockchain, sha256, sha, tron, sha-3

I want to convert a TRON address in the HEX format into Base58 one without TronWeb. I can't use JS or Python either. I want to understand the algorithm to then implement it in a language of my choice.

As per https://github.com/tronprotocol/documentation/blob/master/TRX/Tron-overview.md#62-mainnet-addresses-begin-with-41

```
//(1)
address = 41||sha3[12,32): 415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f 

//(2)
sha256_0 = sha256(address): 06672d677b33045c16d53dbfb1abda1902125cb3a7519dc2a6c202e3d38d3322 

//(3)
sha256_1 = sha256(sha256_0): 9b07d5619882ac91dbe59910499b6948eb3019fafc4f5d05d9ed589bb932a1b4 
checkSum = sha256_1[0, 4): 9b07d561 
addchecksum = address || checkSum: 415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f9b07d561 

//last step
base58Address = Base58(addchecksum): TJCnKsPa7y5okkXvQAidZBzqx3QyQ6sxMW
```

However, SHA3-256 applied to `415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f` won't generate anything remotely similar to

```
//(2) 
06672d677b33045c16d53dbfb1abda1902125cb3a7519dc2a6c202e3d38d3322`
```

For instance, using an online converter

https://md5calc.com/hash/sha3-256/415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f

`SHA3-256(415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f)`

will produce

`64a35f3345223990cc06d1b356e5ac7421f5e15f4dbe0fd934957fb9f0aab76e`

and there's **no part in it** iidentical to the one in TRON documenation.

What's the matter?

**update1**

The 1st 2 commands have produced the correct results after I've replace HEX representation with the bytes.

But the `//last step` still hasn't:

```
//actual HEX string, not bytes

Base58.encode("415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f9b07d561") 

===> 

eJJL2m8pSeN7rACLEzRb5JMoJsZSXfFLZgGmC6LbKpdrALZMqKW6MDShkwh5xotJX4vc
```

Comment: You should hash the bytes and not the hexadecimal string representation of the bytes

Comment: @M.Spiller Ok. The 1st 2 commands have produced the correct results. But the 3rd one not. `Base58.encode("415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f9b07d561")` ===> `eJJL2m8pSeN7rACLEzRb5JMoJsZSXfFLZgGmC6LbKpdrALZMqKW6MDShkwh5xotJX4vc`

Comment: I'm using a HEX representation of the bytes for `Base58.encode(...)` because this is what has to be used there. Right?

Comment: Same as above...
No, you should work on the bytes, not on any string representation. The doc on github also links to a Java implementation. That should make it clear.

Comment: @M.Spiller - finally! Victory!